# Using WHERE NOT EXISTS in Sqlite returns syntax error

Tags: sqlite, discord.js

(This relates to a Discord bot using Discord.js and sqlite v3, NOT sqlite3)
I'm currently trying to use WHERE NOT EXISTS to add a row to my Sqlite table, but only if there isn't a row where "serverid" is the ID of the current server and the type spam already.

I tried it with this:

```
sql.run(`INSERT INTO filters WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM filters WHERE serverid = "${msg.guild.id}" AND type = "Spam") (serverid, type, active, action, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`, msg.guild.id, `Spam`, 0, `delete`, 60)
```

This works if there ISN'T a row with that ID and type yet, but as soon as it does exist, I get a "syntax error at: WHERE".
It doesn't tell me which WHERE the problem is, and I double checked the syntax multiple times and it should be fine.
Does this not work in sqlite? Or did I get the syntax wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of the query is wrong.
You should use `INSERT ... SELECT` instead of `INSERT ... VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO filters (serverid, type, active, action, time)
SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM filters WHERE serverid = "${msg.guild.id}" AND type = "Spam")`
```

Comment: That's strange, I use my original syntax everywhere else in the project and it works just fine. But thanks, that solved it!